# Suggestions for self-studying experimental techniques

Tags: experiment

I would appreciate any suggestion regarding self-studying experimental techniques used in biology for a theoretical scientist (candidate).

Maybe I should be more specific. I'm a biology major, but took as little experimental courses as possible, and I didn't paid much attention to those I took. (shame on me, right). Then I got a MS in applied math. When I revisit my molecular biology/genetics and biochemistry textbooks, I realized that they are mostly descriptive.

An experiment/technique oriented textbook would be very helpful for me, especially if it will also provide an overview of the methods.

My purpose is not the make up for the lost undergrad years, change my research orientation or master experimental skills. I'm aware that this is not achievable by reading some texts. My sole purpose is to not get lost on theory/experiment interface. When someone asks how something could be proven experimentally, I want to know what options are there in the field.

Comment: and I also wonder, why there is no self-study tag on biology.SE

Comment: Are you mostly interested in molecular biology oriented methods?

Comment: yes, especially genome sequencing and transcriptome quantifying methods

Comment: My undergrad mol. biol. book showed a lot of the original experimental data for establishing mol. biol. mechanisms, but it's pre-shotgun sequencing. It doesn't have a lot of the new, PCR-based stuff, because much of the basic biology was worked out before then. Should I hunt down that textbook title?

Comment: thank you, but I think I need something which covers also moder techniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot more highly recommend [Molecular Cloning 4 ed.](http://www.molecularcloning.com/). It is a really comprehensive text which covers numerous molecular biology experimental techniques including different types of PCR.

EDIT: Also, there are some great suggestions for other books and websites that also cover molecular biology techniques in the answers to this question: [Short, concise, practical manual for doing experimental biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21750/short-concise-practical-manual-for-doing-experimental-biology?rq=1)